# « de représentants du bien » ou « d’être les représentants du bien »?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, constructions, formulation, reformulation

Après tous les actes barbares qui ont été perpétrés au nom de dieu, les religions ne sont pas dignes

…de représentants du bien.

…d’être les représentants du bien.

D’autres tournures qui me viennent spontanément à l’esprit:

…de se poser en défenseurs du bien.

…de se proclamer les défenseurs du bien.

N’hésitez pas à me donner d’autres propositions qui s’inscrivent dans cette idée, idéalement des tournures plus élégantes ou des phrases qui présentent l’idée sous une autre forme ou un autre style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ni l'une ni l'autre des deux tournures ne convient ! Il  manque une idée dans la première et dans la seconde celle d'introduire par  l'intermédiaire du verbe « être »  la qualité de représentant du bien n'est pas très expressive ; c'est même vague : qu'est-ce qu'on peut penser ? Seraient-elles  vraiment les représentants  du bien et  elles n'en  sont pas digne ? Seraient-elles plutôt avancées comme telles et  cette possibilité se révélerait irréaliste ? Sur ce point les deux tournures suivantes sont irréprochables, seulement elles indiquent que l'idée est très particulière : il s'agit d'une tendance des religions à considérer cet attribut le leur (se proclamer, se poser en, se faire passer pour, s'imposer comme…)

Answer (score 2):

*Après tous les actes barbares perpétrés au nom de Dieu, les religions sont bien mal placées pour promouvoir le bien.*